# Retina media queries for iphone using HTML

Tags: iphone, html, css

I'm trying to get retina to work on iPhone app (HTML, CSS3 and JS). It is for iphone app.

I've tried as below and it doesn't work for two .png images as below?

HTML:

```
  <div id='slider13' class='swipe; myImage; myImage2;'>
<ul>
<li style='display:block'><div><img style="vertical-align: bottom" src="**images/10a.png**" border="0" ></div></li>  
<li style='display:block'><div><img style="vertical-align: bottom" src="images/10b.svg" border="0" ></div></li>
<li style='display:block'><div><img style="vertical-align: bottom" src="**images/10c.png**" border="0" ></div></li>
<li style='display:block'><div><img style="vertical-align: bottom" src="images/7b.svg" border="0" ></div></li>
<!-- <li style='display:none'><div><img style="vertical-align: bottom" alt="" title="" border="0" class="shadow" /></div></li> -->
</ul>
```

CSS3:

```
.myImage {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
-webkit-background-size: 100% auto.;
background: url("../images/10a.png");
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
screen and (max-moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
and screen (max-device-width: 320px) {
.myImage {
    background: url("../images/10a@2x.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the semicolons in your classlist.

Comment: Do you mean this class='swipe; myImage; myImage2;

Comment: Yes, remove the semicolons.

Comment: class='swipe myImage myImage2; Is that correct?

Comment: No. `class="swipe myImage myImage2"`.

Comment: It work ok but not as retina.

Comment: Too much useless/specific code, low-quality english, no indentation, basic syntax errors, no follow-up, title too general. Actually I think this would be a good candidate for the garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's just a syntax issue, missing the 'only'. Try:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}
```

There are some more options at http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Comment: @Irishgirl Just add in something like `and (min-width: 480px)` for it to be iPhone only.